# find string by mask in php

Tags: php, masking

In the DB I have some strings like:

```
1. BBD0G.ABAEBABGBAB-AAL----BA.LLRV--B--B--.H----A---
2. BBD0G.AAAEAAAGAAA-NAL----CA.LLRV--------.H----A---
3. BBD0G.AAABCBAGAAA-A--------.LLRV------A-.H--------
```

All strings have same length.

How can I find all strings based on a mask like:

```
*******B*****************B************A***********
```

It should not be a rule based on value position, but a general rule based on entire mask.

Thank you!

Comment: What code have you tried yet?

Comment: I don't know what to try to make it working apart of substr and position of each digit... but this is not a clever solution ... maybe users will choose to filter based on 30 chars... What I need is a function to take the entire mask and check what strings are coresponding.

Comment: for example, that mask I used should return only string 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to filter with your sql query. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '_______B_________________B____________A___________';
```

The wildcard _ exactly one character. For more information see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$template = "\*{7}B\*{17}B\*{12}A\*{11}";

$your_db_string = ...
$result = preg_match($template, $your_db_string);
// check $result...
```